# Sed replace alphabet to uppercase after period

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have just come through a [sed tutorial](http://www.techsakh.com/2016/10/10/sed-tutorial-for-linux-administrator-daily-stream-editing-task/) article. Can somebody please explain this command for me (it changes alphabet to upper case after period)

```
sed -E 's/(^[a]|\. [a-z])/\U&\E/g' filename.txt
```

Comment: I personally don't mind helping out with homework, but it would be interesting to hear your own thoughts about this first. Best regards.

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial that you linked to is very superficial.

If you want to use sed seriously, I suggest http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html
instead.

The `s` command in sed takes a `from pattern`, a `to string`, and optionally some `flags`. Traditionally these are separated by a `/` character but any punctuation can be used and this is sensible to do if either the from or to arguments contain / characters.

So in this case the flags are `g`, the from pattern is `(^[a]|\. [a-z])` and the to string is `\U&\E`

At this point you need to know how to understand the from pattern. The `()` characters are used to group parts of the pattern together. The `|` is an `or` operations so `this|that` would match either `this` or `that`. The `^` matches the start of a line, and the `[a]` matches the letter `a`, so `^[a]` matches a letter `a` at the start of a line. The `\.` matches a `.` character, the space matches a space, and the `[a-z]` matches a character between `a` and `z` inclusive (Hopefully this is all the lower case letters and nothing else). Putting this together you get `\. [a-z]` matches a full stop (period) followed by a space followed by a letter between `a` and `z` inclusive.

The to string `\U&\E` is decoded as follows. the `&` is the characters that matched the from pattern. The `\U` says to convert what follows to upper case and the `\E` says to end the conversion. The \U and \E are gnu extensions to sed. Here is the POSIX [sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

The `g` flags say to repeat the matching as many times as it can and do the substitutions.

So the code you copied from the tutorial converts *either* a lower case a at the start of a line or a sequence of "period space lower_case_letter" to upper case.